# Compare 3 columns in two different data frames and action based on comparison result

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to compare 3 columns in two different data frames, and updating a 'Flag' based on the comparison results.

For example,

```
df_1 <- data.frame(x=seq(1,5,1),y=seq(1.5,5.5,1),z=LETTERS[1:5],Flag=0)
```

[image]

```
df_2 <- data.frame(l=c(1.2,10,3.2,5,5.2),k=c("A","F","P","D","E"))
```

[image]

if the row-wise element of df_2 (col=l) is in between row-wise element of df_1 (cols =x, y) AND row-wise element in  df_1 (col=z) matches with the row-wise element of df_2(col = k), then flag is updated to 1, else 0. So the expected output is

[image]

My code thus far :

```
df_1 %>% mutate(Flag=map_chr(
  .x=c(as.character(df_1$z),as.numeric(df_1$x),as.numeric(df_1$y)),
  .f= ~if_else(condition = all(.x == as.character(df_2$k) & x >= as.numeric(df_2$l)& x<=as.numeric(df_2$k)),true="1",false="0")
))
```

> Error :
> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `Flag = map_chr(...)`.
> ✖ `Flag` must be size 5 or 1, not 15.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

```
warnings()
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: Problem while computing `Flag = map_chr(...)`.
> ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
> 2: Problem while computing `Flag = map_chr(...)`.
> ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
> 3: Problem while computing `Flag = map_chr(...)`.
> ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
> ... 15 times
> As the dataframes are quite large, I am trying to avoid loops.

Many thanks @zephryl for answering my original question (above)

A variation of this problem is : one row in df_1 to be compared with all the rows in df_2 and flag "incremented" accordingly.

For example,
df_1

[image]

df_2

[image: ![enter image description here]

Expected output

[image]

Thanks in advance!

I am trying to avoid loops as the dataframe is huge

I have already solved using loops

```r
for(i in seq(1,nrow(df_1_new),1))
   {for(j in seq(1,nrow(df_2),1))
      {if(df_1_new$z[i] == df_2$k[j] & df_1_new$x[i] <= df_2$l[j] & 
       df_1_new$y[i] >= df_2$l[j])
          {df_1_new$Flag[i] = df_1_new$Flag[i]+1}}}
```

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, no need to use `map()` or loops, you can just directly test your conditions thanks to vectorized operations:

```
df_1$Flag <- ifelse(df_2$l >= df_1$x & df_2$l <= df_1$y & df_1$z == df_2$k, 1, 0)
```

or,

```
df_1$Flag <- with(cbind(df_1, df_2), ifelse(l >= x & l <= y & z == k, 1, 0))
```

or,

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 <- df_1 %>% 
  mutate(Flag = if_else(df_2$l >= x & df_2$l <= y & z == df_2$k, 1, 0))
```

Result from all 3 approaches:

```
#> df_1
  x   y z Flag
1 1 1.5 A    1
2 2 2.5 B    0
3 3 3.5 C    0
4 4 4.5 D    0
5 5 5.5 E    1
```

For the second question, you can iterate over `x`, `y`, and `z` in `df_1` using [`purrr::pmap_dbl()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pmap.html). (Note I renamed the second version of `df_2` to `df_2_2` since it had different values.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(Flag = pmap_dbl(
    list(x, y, z),
    \(x, y, z) sum(df_2_2$l >= x & df_2_2$l <= y & z == df_2_2$k)
  ))
```

```
  x   y z Flag
1 1 1.5 A    2
2 2 2.5 B    0
3 3 3.5 C    2
4 4 4.5 D    0
5 5 5.5 E    0
```